# iPhone app startup

Tags: iphone, startup

How do I make my iPhone app start at the same place each time, i.e. my 'home' screen? I do NOT want the user to return to where they were last time they played - right in the middle of gameplay - but that's what's happening.
Thanks in advance for any tips!

Answer (score 6):

You need to set the `UIApplicationExitsOnSuspend` key in your info.plist file to `YES`.  Then the app will quit when the home button is pressed, and launch fresh when it is opened again.

Comment: Hey thank! - but I don't even see that member in my info.plist - is it an iPhone4-only field?

Comment: It only does anything on iPhone 4, but you can safely add it to the info.plist file for earlier operating systems; it will be ignored on 3.x and 2.x.

Comment: Just create a new entry in the plist, paste the key in the key column, make the type column BOOL, and check the box--it'll work.  It just won't necessarily get a plain english translation for it's name in Xcode.

Answer (score 3):

This is presumably only happening because your app isn't really being stopped - it's simply being backgrounded. (If you double click the home button whilst viewing springboard does it show up at the bottom? If so, it's still running.)

You can disable this behaviour (so your app quits when the user hits the home button) by setting the `UIApplicationExitsOnSuspend` key (known as "Application does not run in background" within Xcode) in your info.plist file. See Apple's [Information Property List Key Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/general/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/iPhoneOSKeys.html) docs for more information.

Alternatively, you could simply capture the `applicationDidEnterBackground:` [UIApplicationDelegate](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIApplicationDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html) method in your app's add delegate and handle the situation from there programatically. (i.e.: Do whatever you need to do to reset your app back to the 'home' screen, etc.)

Comment: aha yes, it's in the background - but I don't have the UIApplicationExitsOnSuspend field showing in my info.plist file - as if it thinks it's a 3.2 file?

Answer (score 2):

```
- (void)applicationWillResignActive:(UIApplication *)application {

[self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];   

}
```

/*
     Sent when the application is about to move from active to inactive state. This can occur for certain types of temporary interruptions (such as an incoming phone call or SMS message) or when the user quits the application and it begins the transition to the background state.
     Use this method to pause ongoing tasks, disable timers, and throttle down OpenGL ES frame rates. Games should use this method to pause the game.
     */

Comment: How do you even know if he's using a UINavigationController?

Comment: /*
     Sent when the application is about to move from active to inactive state. This can occur for certain types of temporary interruptions (such as an incoming phone call or SMS message) or when the user quits the application and it begins the transition to the background state.
     Use this method to pause ongoing tasks, disable timers, and throttle down OpenGL ES frame rates. Games should use this method to pause the game.
     */

Answer (score 1):

Set `UIApplicationExitsOnSuspend` to `YES` int the  `Info.plist`.

Comment: Thanks for all these responses! - OK I see now it's an iPhone4 field; but don't I want to target 3.2 so it runs on old phones?