# iphone:terminate application in iphone

Tags: iphone

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [quit app in iOS4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3421400/quit-app-in-ios4)

hi i am beginner in iphone developement. i am working on a iphone app copatible for iphone4.
i am showing a alert view and on selecting a yes navigating to brouwser.its ok but my application going in background.but i want it to be terminate and shuld be relaunch on clicking on app icon.

```
if (alertView.tag==222) {
        if (buttonIndex==0) {
            [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL: [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://itunes.apple.com/"]];

        }
}
```

also it is goingin bground when i am clicking on home button.
i want app should be terminated from background also.

Comment: @Daniel you should never call exit.

Comment: Other possible duplicates: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3227736/iphone-avoid-save-state, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5565730/iphone-app-startup, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6127560/how-do-i-tell-ios-that-i-do-not-want-the-app-to-stay-in-the-background, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4437619/make-app-without-of-multitasking-support, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6516519/how-to-restart-a-application-without-going-to-recent-worked-page-when-we-exit-in

Comment: Read this: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#qa/qa1561/_index.html

Answer (score 0):

Set the `Application does not run in background` in your info.plist to YES

Comment: hi thnks but on a specific condition i want my app to be terminated(background app deletion)but every time clicking on home button its going to be terminated.

Comment: Cant really follow you, but setting this to yes stop you app from running in the background. This mean it will stop running when the user presses the homebutton or you open an other app via `openURL` method.

Answer (score -1):

Add `UIApplicationExitsOnSuspend` / `Application does not run in background` to your `Info.plist`.

Comment: i applied it but every time it will terminate the app and app will start from begining.on a specific condition i want app to be terminated.